# Split Horizon DNS Causes Entire Network DNS Failure

Tags: dnsmasq

### The Problem

I have setup a Raspberry Pi 4 on my local network. This device is both a web-server and (now, by necessity) a DNS-server. This device needs to be reached from both inside, as well as outside the network. I have a **public domain name** being updated via ***DynDNS*** service that receives my router's public IP. When I use the domain that points to my IP, I then use port forwarding to route all incoming web traffic to the PI's private IP over port 80. When I use this configuration to then visit my domain in a browser (while connected to another network than the PI it on) ***It works!***. That is; I go to the domain, it resolves as my routers public IP, port forwarding send the port 80 request to the PI, it serves the page. ***Voila!***

The issue is when I try to reach this same page from ***inside*** the network. When I use this same domain name, it times-out and will not resolve (because it resolves as the public IP of my router, not the private IP of this web-server).

Using split-horizon DNS, my plan is to use this web-server as a DNS-server as well, to force all devices on my internal network to resolve this domain name as it's private IP rather than it's public IP. Once I leave my network the domain will be resolved by other name servers so it will resolve to the public IP (so it will be fine).

### What I Have Done

- I have setup the pi with no desktop and only CLI
- I connected the pi to a LAN connection in my router
- I have setup SSH and opened the ufw ports for port 22
- Downloaded, installed and setup DNSMasq
- Opened port 53 in my server firewall (ufw)
- Went into the Router management page in the box given to me by my ISP. I pointed both of the primary and secondary DNS servers from their defaults to the private IP of my PI server
- Copied both of the primary and secondary DNS server IP addresses from the ISP Router management page (previous step) and put them in my DNSMasq config file (found in /etc/dnsmasq.conf) under the key `server=ip.ip.ip.ip`. I am not going to give these ip's so this serves as a mock for how I entered both the primary and secondary, each on their own line right after the other
- I Used the following DNSMasq config settings: domain-needed, bogus-priv, cache-size=750, log-queries, log-faciliy=/var/log/dnsmasq.log, server=isp.ip.primary.0, server=isp.ip.secondary.0, server=8.8.8.8, server=8.8.4.4, dhcp-mac, dhcp-reply-delay
- There are no errors in my dnsmasq.log file
- There are no errors in `sudo service dnsmasq status`
- Cannot seem to get into my ISP router's logs. I can see them but theres so many that it crashes the entire webpage when trying to scroll through them all

### Outcome

No device on my entire network can now resolve any domains at all until I change back to my default ISP primary/secondary

#### What am I missing or doing wrong??

Comment: tl;dr, what does `dig @<your internal dns ip> <name>` says and what does `dig <name>` says? (First is explicitly sent to DNS IP, 2nd is using local resolver configuration.)

Comment: @JiriB the first, `dig @my_ip <domain>` showed a response of the correct IP (I think, I don't use dig often so I assume I want to look at ";; server: __IP__"). However, I think this IP was right because of the @my_ip part. The `dig <domain>` response (again in ;; server: __ip__) gave me the private IP of my router.... so I am now very confused.

Comment: What is *@my_ip*, it should be IP of your local DNS server. Not to be confused with `dig`, see `$ dig +noall +answer @192.168.1.1 install.home.arpa. A`, one single line of answer should apper (of course modify input).

Comment: I am not interested in revealing my domain but my private IP is fine. I just did `dig +noall +answer @192.168.2.143 my.domain.com A` and it responded with `my.domain.com. 0 IN A 192.168.2.143`. However, (again) I think its because you got me to put my private IP in the dig command. I am not sure how this helps. When I just do `dig my.domain.com` I get the private IP of my home router for some reason.

Comment: If you got private IP (of your router) for `dig my.domain.com` instead of valid private IP, then you obviously have mess in your DNS.

Comment: @JiriB How is this helpful?...

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dnsmasq` as your both authoritativ and recursive DNS server, then you forgot to show related lines from `dnsmasq` configuration for your zone.

See https://www.onderka.com/computer-und-netzwerk/autoritativer-dns-server-mit-dnsmasq

Basic is know your local DNS settings of course. In the next example, I simulated owning of *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*, and using split DNS to resolve differently from local network.

```
$ nslookup www.example.com 8.8.4.4
Server:         8.8.4.4
Address:        8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
Name:   www.example.com
Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946

$ nslookup www.example.com
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Name:   www.example.com
Address: 192.168.1.2
```

(I do not use `dnsmasq` but that's not the problem.)

Comment: I forgot to show what lines? I copied everything I have in my conf file. This example shows me output from nslookup, not how to solve my problem. Saying, "just know your local DNS settings" is like explaining how to drive to someone by saying, "You just drive...".

Comment: Is `dnsmasq` your local auth/recursive DNS? If so, you miss any records for your internal DNS names, like *auth-zone*... I give up.

Comment: I believe the setup I mentioned would involve Authoritative from inside the network and recursive outside the network. The domain is hosted elsewhere and pointed to my public IP. Everything works fine outside the network, just not inside as I mentioned. So inside the network I need an Auth on the same domain that is working outside my network.

Comment: *So inside the network I need an Auth on the same domain that is working outside my network.* Still uknown if you use `dnsmasq` on your LAN, if so follow the first list in the answer if dnmasq documentation is not clear how to setup authoritative role on dnsmasq.

Comment: My LAN is controlled by a box that my ISP gives me. I have a management page which I can use to configure some things, but not as much as my PI. I have no idea if they use dnsmasq in that box.

Comment: So configure split DNS (dnsmasq, unbound, bind - overkill) on your RPI and change your ISP router DHCP settings to send your DNS IP to DHCP clients.

Comment: How do you change router settings to send DNS IP to DHCP clients?